# What is the correct use of dashes in complex phrasal adjectives in British English used in scientific writing?

Tags: hyphenation, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, compound-words

Are dashes used correctly according to British English rules in the phrases below that appear in published peer-reviewed scientific journals and related articles? If not, *why not* and what is the correct rule of grammar in British English?

The answer to [How should a multiple-word noun be punctuated within a compound adjective?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/289021/how-should-a-multiple-word-noun-be-punctuated-within-a-compound-adjective) provides rules from US style guides only and does not sufficiently clarify  hyphenation rules to determine correct use in British English for the specific phrases below.

1. **Feral predator-free area** (an area that is free of feral predators; also used to describe project, ecosystem, haven etc.)
2. **Feral-predator free habitat** (a habitat from which feral predators have been removed)
3. **Camera trapping-survey design** (the design of a survey of animals using camera-traps)
4. **Camera-trap sampling designs** (designs for sampling animal populations using camera-traps)
5. **Predator baiting program** (a program to reduce the number of predators, such as feral cats, through poison baiting)
6. **Feral cat control strategy** (also feral cat baiting programs)
7. **Invasive predator control programs** (a program to control invasive predators)
8. **Feral cat poison baiting event** (a single event where poison baits were distributed to control feral cats)

I am not concerned with punctuation for compound nouns or adjectives *within* the phrases, but rather the correct punctuation for the entire phrase *as it appears in published work*. Each phrase could be written as a full sentence but in scientific writing it is preferable to be concise, especially when concepts are referred to repeatedly.

---

<sub>**Sources of examples**:</sub>

<sup>01) https://www.environment.nsw.gov.au/topics/parks-reserves-and-protected-areas/park-management/return-of-threatened-and-declining-species/feral-predator-free-areas & https://www.nationalparks.nsw.gov.au/conservation-programs/feral-predator-free-project & https://www.australianwildlife.org/australias-largest-feral-predator-free-area-declared-at-mallee-cliffs-national-park/ & https://www.mtrothwell.com.au/about
https://uplifting.network/australia-creates-the-largest-feral-predator-free-haven-on-its-mainland-1789/</sup>
<sup>02) https://www.tidbinbilla.act.gov.au/wildlife/overview</sup>
<sup>03) https://www.publish.csiro.au/wr/WR19175</sup>
<sup>04) https://researchers.cdu.edu.au/en/publications/multiple-cameras-required-to-reliably-detect-feral-cats-in-northe</sup>
<sup>05) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479720316169?dgcid=author</sup>
<sup>06) https://www.dpaw.wa.gov.au/images/documents/about/science/cswa/articles/128.pdf & https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14486563.2021.1927211</sup>
<sup>07) https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0301479720316169?dgcid=author</sup>
<sup>08) https://www.publish.csiro.au/wr/WR19175</sup>